# Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM Nodejs, Yandex, Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, yandex

I am trying to send email from my NodeJs Server using Yandex. Below is the process of creating transporter

```
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Yandex',
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL,
                pass: process.env.PASSWORD
            }
        });
```

But it always fails showing the below messege:

{ Error: Message failed: 554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1578999406-wC5neov7vv-ui00GIiO

> ```
>  at SMTPConnection._formatError (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:605:19)
>  at SMTPConnection._actionSMTPStream (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1478:34)
>  at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:968:2
> ```
>
> 2)
>        at SMTPConnection._processResponse (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:764:20)
>        at SMTPConnection._onData (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:570:14)
>        at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (F:\ProjectFolder\Office\MXQ\Backend\mxq_server_firebase_functions\functions\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:522:47)
>        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
>        at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
>        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
>        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
>        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
>      code: 'EMESSAGE',
>      response:
>       '554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1578999406-wC5neov7vv-ui00GIiO',
>      responseCode: 554,
>      command: 'DATA' }

Is it a problem with Yandex or from my side?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, but not all mailboxes can't accept emails.
Then, I found the answer in the official support documentation:
https://yandex.com/support/mail/bounces/other/message-rejected-under-suspicion-of-spam.html?lang=en

Comment: While this might answer the question, please consider including more of the relevant info from the link, in the space provided here.

Answer (score 1):

It is on your side, I had such an error before with another provider (not yendex), and solved it by signing the email, you need to get a DKIM and sign your email with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

After a little bit research I applied method below :
I opened web interface of Yandex Email and manually sent some emails to my own email addresses, and then I've replied this emails back.

Just to prove to the system that this email account sends real letters .. it's not just a robot account.

P.S:
I was sending a welcome email to customers by using Nodemailer and Handlebars for the HTML templates. I'm not sure it's related.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and I searched for the same and came here, the link posted by @Akira_Ant I clicked and I logged into the yandex service and then the mail from then on started flowing normally, so for me logging into the yandex.mail and then sending such signup mails [in fact all sorts password reset,otp and all in my case] worked. So i guess the solution might be logging in normally and keep logged in and then the service knows that the person is logged in so it may not be spam.